# spark spark-submit org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_38_piece0 of broadcast_38

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

Hello，I am a noob in spark.These days I am using spark-submit to handle the SQL operation on the files of HDFS. Here is my question. Please pick it if I'm wrong.In my view,as soon as the `spark-submit` finished, the RDD cached in memory will be cleared. But i want to reuse the RDD cached in memory.

So I let the program that will be executed by spark-submit don't quit ,and act as a server：listens on a port, receives queries from socket continually,does the SQL queries and returns the results to the clients. But the program can only handle once.

The client will send to server 10 queries in one time.Only the first 10 SQL jobs that the server received from one client can be successful. The next jobs will be aborted all.And the exception as follow:

> Exception in thread "Thread-47" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 51, 10.10.108.63): java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_29_piece0 of broadcast_29
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1178)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_29_piece0 of broadcast_29
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:175)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1175)
>       ... 11 more
>
> Driver stacktrace:
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1280)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1268)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>       at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1493)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1455)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1444)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1813)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1826)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1839)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1910)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:905)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
>       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:904)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:338)
>       at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:47)
>       at cn.ac.ict.chinasoft.netty.SQLServerHandler.runSQLOnSpark(SQLServerHandler.java:40)
>       at cn.ac.ict.chinasoft.netty.SQLServerHandler.access$000(SQLServerHandler.java:17)
>       at cn.ac.ict.chinasoft.netty.SQLServerHandler$ExecuteSql.run(SQLServerHandler.java:63)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_29_piece0 of broadcast_29
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1178)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       ... 1 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_29_piece0 of broadcast_29
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
>       at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
>       at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:175)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1175)
>       ... 11 more
>   15/09/11 08:21:48 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 1 in stage 15.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
>   15/09/11 08:21:48 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 15.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
>   15/09/11 08:21:48 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 16.0 (TID 56) on executor 10.10.108.63: java.io.IOException (org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_35_piece0 of broadcast_35) [duplicate 6]
>   15/09/11 08:21:48 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.2 in stage 16.0 (TID 63, 10.10.108.63, ANY, 2213 bytes)
>   15/09/11 08:21:48 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 12
>   15/09/11 08:21:48 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 12 (collect at SQLServerHandler.java:40) failed in 0.210 s
>   15/09/11 08:21:48 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 12 failed: collect at SQLServerHandler.java:40, took 0.246739 s
>   15/09/11 08:21:48 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 13
>   15/09/11 08:21:48 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 13 (collect at SQLServerHandler.java:40) failed in 0.206 s
>   15/09/11 08:21:48 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 13 failed: collect at SQLServerHandler.java:40, took 0.231847 s

Please help me or give some suggestions on my purpose.Thanks!

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)._: